# Can we perturb a low rank map to a full rank map in a smooth way?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, matrix-rank, perturbation-theory, stability-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be smooth. Can we find, for every $\epsilon>0$, a $C^1$ map $\tilde f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ **of full rank** such that

$\|df-d\tilde f\|_{C^0}<\epsilon$?

Note that what I require is weaker than $\|f-\tilde f\|_{C^1}<\epsilon$, I only want the differentials to be uniformly close.

The point is that pointwise, for every real $n \times n$ matrix $A$, and every $\epsilon>0$, there exist an invertible matrix $\tilde A$ such that $\|A-\tilde A\|<\epsilon$. **The question is whether we can always create a smooth and exact perturbation.** (i.e. I want $d\tilde f$ to be everywhere invertible).

I am fine if this perturbation cannot be done on the whole space, but only on a fixed "part of it"- e.g. I am OK with restricting the domain to be the unit disk. (but I don't want to be forced to shrink the domain to a disk with a radius which depends on $\epsilon$).

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but in dimension one, if we take $f(x) = \sin(x)$, you're asking for a small perturbation in the derivative $\cos(x)+ g(x)$ which doesn't have zeros, which should be impossible when $\|g\|_{C^0} < \epsilon \le 1/2$?

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I thought for a moment that dimension $1$ might be especially rigid compared to other dimensions, when we have "more room". However, I think that this would fail in high dimensions as well: We can take $f$ to have derivative which admits values of arbitrarily large norms, with determinants of different signs. Then, the differential of any $C^1$ map with everywhere invertible differential should lie inside one of the connected components of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$, and I guess that we could get a contradiction from there. (but I am not sure).

Comment: The above should extend to a counterexample in any dimension via $f(x) = (\sin(x_1),0,\dots,0)$. Then $df(x)h = (cos(x_1)h_1,0,\dots,0)$ and the same problem arises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done locally (that is, for any point $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and any $\varepsilon > 0$, you can get an approximation that works on $B(p,r)$ where $r$ depends on $\varepsilon$ and $p$) but definitely cannot be done globally. Let $n = 1$ and consider $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{2}$. If $g \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^1$ map with non-vanishing derivative then $g'(x) > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ or $g'(x) < 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. In any case,

$$ \| f' - g' \|_{\infty} = \infty. $$

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I thought for a moment that dimension $1$ might be especially rigid compared to other dimensions, when we have "more room". However, I think that this would fail in high dimensions as well: We can take $f$ to have derivative which admits values of arbitrarily large norms, with determinants of different signs. Then, the differential of any $C^1$ map with everywhere invertible differential should lie inside one of the connected components of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$, and I guess that we could get a contradiction from there. (but I am not sure).

Comment: I guess that for the local construction, you can just take an affine map as an approximating map?

Comment: @AsafShachar: In higher dimensions, just consider $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \mapsto \left( x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}, \frac{x_n^2}{2} \right)$. Locally, you can consider $\tilde{f}(x_1, \dots, x_n) = f(x_1, \dots, x_n) + \lambda (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ for small non-zero $\lambda$.

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure that $d\tilde f$ in your construction would be invertible for *small* $\lambda$? We have $d\tilde f=df+\lambda Id$, but $df$ is not necessarily a "small" perturbation compared to $\lambda$ (so it's not clear to me why $df+\lambda Id$ should be invertible).

Comment: @AsafShachar: For any matrix $A$, the matrix $A + \lambda I$ is not invertible iff $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Hence $A + \lambda I$ is invertible for all but finitely many $\lambda$'s and in particular, it is invertible for small non-zero values of $\lambda$.